# Azure Service Bus Topic Consume

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have setup Azure Service Bus topic and when ASB is loaded with like 100K messages, the message consumption is very slow. I have 10-15 instances of a service running, which listens to the topic but the message consumption is too slow and takes about 2hrs to process all the ASB messages.

My setup -

```
subscriptionClient.OnMessageAsync(message => InvokeCallbackAsync(message, callback));

private Task InvokeCallbackAsync(BrokeredMessage message, Func<IServiceBusMessage, Task> callback)
{
    if (subscriptionClient.IsClosed)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    if (!Guid.TryParse(message.CorrelationId, out Guid trackingId))
    {
        trackingId = Guid.NewGuid();
     }

     DiagnosticContext.SetCurrentRequestData(trackingId);

     return callback(new ServiceBusMessage(message));
}
```

I noticed that the `OnMessageAsync` can also take `OnMessageOptions` and by default it has

```
public OnMessageOptions()
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
    AutoComplete = true;
    ReceiveTimeOut = Constants.DefaultOperationTimeout;
    AutoRenewTimeout = Constants.ClientPumpRenewLockTimeout;
}
```

I wasn't able to find relevant examples and explanation to tweak these settings to consume faster.

Any help on this will be helpful.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the specified documentation. I'm trying to identify if tweaking the existing settings can make things better before re-implementing. I'm unable to find documentation with examples to explain the issue better